# Expand UITableViewCell with smooth animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to Animate the transition of a `UITableViewCell` when its height is changed. For this I am using the following lines of code:

```
    [meetingsTable beginUpdates];
    [meetingsTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:changedRow inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [meetingsTable endUpdates];
```

but it is not showing the row height change animation. It just displays the expanded cell. However, if I  remove the line

```
[meetingsTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:changedRow inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

it shows the expected animated height change but the cell is not reloaded. I have tried all the available `UITableViewRowAnimation`options but with no success. I have also tried

```
[meetingsTable reloadData];
```

but it is also not helpful. 
Please suggest what can be the possible solution.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
BMeetingsTableCell *cell;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MEETINGS"];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[BMeetingsTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MEETINGS"];
}

[self customizeCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath forTable:tableView];
return cell;
}

- (void)customizeCell:(BMeetingsTableCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forTable:(UITableView*)tableView shouldReload:(BOOL)shouldReload{
NSDictionary *event;
if (isSearching) {
    event = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[searchedData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}else if ([tableView isEqual:_activeMeetingsTable])
    event = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[activeEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
else if ([tableView isEqual:_completedMeetingTable])
    event = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[completedEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSArray *partArr;
UILabel *showTimeLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:9];
UIImageView *showNewMeetingIcon = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:8];
[showTimeLbl setHidden:YES];
[showNewMeetingIcon setHidden:YES];
cell.delegate = self;
cell.tag = indexPath.row;
NSMutableArray* foundConts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *tempPartArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in [event valueForKey:@"users"]) {
    [tempPartArr addObject:dict];
}
partArr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempPartArr];
if ([displayName length]==0) displayName = numberString;
NSDictionary *participant = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:inviteStat, @"inviteStatus", displayName, @"displayName", nil];
        [foundConts addObject:participant];
    }
}
if ([allParticipants count]> indexPath.row) {
    [allParticipants replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:invitedConts];
}else
    [allParticipants addObject:invitedConts];
if ([tableView isEqual:_meetingsTable]  && selectedRow == indexPath.row) {
    cell.participants = [NSArray arrayWithArray:foundConts];
    [cell.contsTable setHidden:NO];
    //        [cell.arrowButton setSelected:YES];
    [cell.userImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"expandedProfilePic.png"]];
}else{
    [cell.userImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ProfileImage.png"]];
    [cell.contsTable setHidden:YES];
    //        [cell.arrowButton setSelected:NO];
}


[cell.tapProfileBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(expandDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.tapProfileBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.title setText:[event valueForKey:@"subject"]];

NSString* location;
if ([[event valueForKey:@"address"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    location = @"";
}else
    location = [event valueForKey:@"location"];

long long startDateMilliSec = [[event valueForKey:@"start_time_milliseconds"] longLongValue];
NSDate *capturedStartDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:startDateMilliSec];
//
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
NSDateComponents *comps1 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit  fromDate:capturedStartDate];
NSString *theYear = [NSString stringWithFormat:@", %ld", (long)comps1.year];
[dateFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:capturedStartDate];
if ([dateString isEqualToString:@"Today"]||[dateString isEqualToString:@"Tomorrow"]) {
}else{
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:NO];
    dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:capturedStartDate];
}
NSString *amPM = (comps1.hour>=12)?@"PM":@"AM";
NSString *hourStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",(comps1.hour%12)];
dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:theYear withString:@""];
NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%02d %@",hourStr, comps1.minute, amPM];
NSString *displayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ | %@",dateString, timeString];
[cell.date setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ | %@", displayString, location]];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == selectedRow) {
        NSDictionary* event = [activeEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSArray *contacts = [event valueForKey:@"users"];
        int height = ([contacts count]*50)+70;
        return height;
    }
  else return 50
}

- (IBAction)expandDetails:(id)sender{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
selectedRow = btn.tag;
BMeetingsTableCell *changedCell = (BMeetingsTableCell*)[_activeMeetingsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btn.tag inSection:0]];
    [self customizeCell:changedCell atIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btn.tag inSection:0] forTable:_meetingsTable];
    [_meetingsTable beginUpdates];
    [_meetingsTable endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Please append your question with your code as is. Include the height changing logic.

Comment: What specifically is not being updated in the cell?

Comment: the UITableVew (cell.contsTable) inside the UITAbleViewCell is not loaded when expanded.

Comment: It looks like your cell is updating. The problem is likely in your cell customization logic. Try stepping through with breakpoints to see where it is behaving differently than you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the cell without reloading the table view.

I imagine you have your cell customization code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //dequeue cell
    //customize cell at index path
    return cell;
}
```

Move your customization into its own method that takes a cell.

```
- (void)customizeCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   //customize cell
}
```

Now when you need to update a cell you can do this...

```
- (void)rowWasChanged:(NSInteger)changedRow {
    NSIndexPath *changedIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:changedRow inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *changedCell = [self.meetingsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:changedIndex];
    [self customizeCell:changedCell atIndexPath:changedIndex];
    [self.meetingsTable beginUpdates];
    [self.meetingsTable endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Still no success. The height of the cell is changing as expected but the cell is not reloaded.

Comment: Why not? Are you getting a nil cell from cellForRowAtIndexpath?

Comment: The cell is not nil but still I am not getting the cell to load with new data. But if I use reloadRowAtIndexPath after  [self.meetingsTable endUpdates]; , it is displaying the new cell.

Comment: Did you move all of your cell customization code out of cellForRowAtIndexpath and into a common method that also gets called when you need to update your cell?

Answer (score 1):

// Cell animation

```
if(sender.tag == 0) {
    if(sender.on){
        rowHeight1 = 250;
    }else{
        rowHeight1 = 55;
    }
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
    NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
    [tblHealthQuestion reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

}

// for Section animation

```
  NSRange range = NSMakeRange(senctionIndex, 1);//NSMakeRange(0, 1);
        NSIndexSet *section = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
        [tblHealthQuestion reloadSections:section withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation{
    [self reloadSections:sections withRowAnimation:animation];
}
```